# JDBC com.mysql.jdbc.Driver error in jenkins only

Tags: jdbc, ant, jenkins

Hey guys I need a  bit of help. I have recently migrated a java ant project which creates data for my environments onto a vm.  And now i am trying to set up a Jenkins job which which will make run automatically in the evenings when no one is using them. Unfortunatelly I i have come to halt becouse of:

```html
BUILD FAILED
C:\TestData\build.xml:76: Selenium test(s) failed. See the reports!

Total time: 1 minute 0 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

As far a report .. this is it :

```html
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

The thing which baffling for is that i can run the project just fine with ant - f build.xml , of from the IDE, but it just does not work when run via the job.

I doubled the classpath and buildpath i do have the mysql-connector-java.jar My ANT_HOME and PATH system variables are as well set.

In the jenkins instance  have the latest ant plugin installed as  well as the database and database-mysql plugins.

Help would be much appreciated,
Ty

Comment: Looks like a selenium test failed. Do you have application code that connects to mysql? The Mysql driver jar needs to be in the classpath of the junit task.

Comment: Yes i do have a connection to mysql but that same code works just fine when i run it from command line. The driver is in the classpath checked again.

Comment: You are not advised to use the CLASSPATH variable to pass jars to tasks within ANT. Instead much much better to create a path and pass this as a classpath parameter to the junit task. Why??? Well otherwise no garuntee that a build would run the same way on different machines if an environment variable was being used.

Comment: Does ant - f build.xml work in the vm or on your maschine? Where is  the mysql-connector*.jar placed?

Comment: Mark i will try that, but the thing is .. The vm machine on which jenkins is installed and the one on which the build works with ant -f build.xml .. are one and the same so I doubt a build runs differentlly on the same machine.

Comment: the connector is palced in a lib folder within the project along with the junit jar , and the selenium server standalone jar

Comment: If you provide an example of how you run Selenium within the ANT build file? Certainly sounds odd, but there must be a logical explanation.

Comment: <target name="run_all" depends="compile">
  <junit printsummary="yes" fork="yes" errorproperty="junit.error">
  
   <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
   <formatter type="xml" />
   
   <!-- run everything in the com.eviltester.webdriver package -->
   <batchtest todir="${testresults}">
    <fileset dir="${build}" includes="uk/co/tests/AllTests.class" />  
   </batchtest> 
  </junit>